# Creating an asynchronous processo in a java servlet

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets, process, token

I want to create a java servlet that runs an .exe application in the server but as an asynchronous process and returns to the client a hash or token to indentify the process so the client can ask later if the process has finished.

For example:

- A user writes in the web browser something like: http://server:8080/videomanager?action=process
- The servlet receives the request and execute the .exe application but it doens't wait for it to finish, it inmediately responds to the user with a token/hash=12312312ddsadad31231
- The user recieves this token in his web browser
- The user can then send a request like:  http://server:8080/videomanager?action=status&token=12312312ddsadad31231
- The servlet recieves this request and checks if the process it run before (with token 12312312ddsadad31231) is still running and responds to the user with "Finished" or "Still running"

I know that I can use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec() to run the .exe application, but I don't know how to make the servlet leave the process running and responds.

Thanks!

Regards,

Xtian

Answer (score 0):

The [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) returned by `ProcessBuilder` is run asynchronously in the background (it's a separate process), so as soon as you call `.start()` you can have the servlet respond.

If you're seeing the subprocess never finish that would be because you're not reading its [output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--), which you must do in order for the process to continue. You may want to do this in a separate background thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways to implement this:

1. Create a runnable that executes the command (Runtime.exec etc) (a few other things will follow)
2. Create an id lets say a UUID and initialize the status against the id on a persistant storage to say PENDING
3. Use a ThreadPoolExecutor, add the runnable to the workQueue allocated to the threadpool.
4. When the runnable starts executing, it may change the status in say DB to IN_PROGRESS
5. When the task is completed you can mark the status as COMPLETE

Now at any point of time for the request coming in you shall be able to check the status of the task and respond back accordingly.